# Missing access to seemly important attributes for CTP5

Tags: entity-framework, code-first

I need attributes like RelatedTo (and Key for that matter) and I can't seem to find them. The documentation is still very sparse.  Any idea where to go to get these attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Key` attribute is still there but `RelatedTo` came with CTP4 and was removed in CTP5. You should use new CTP5's `InverseProperty` and `ForeignKeyAttribute` attributes instead.

Comment: Thanks --- where is this written up?